# OpenVpn client with multiple remote IP addresses

Tags: openwrt, openvpn

I have 2 openvpn servers running on a raspberry pi 4 (ubuntu server 20.04 LTS), each one behind nat. I have a GL.inet router which will connect to the openvpn servers as a client, i want the client to connect to the next server when the first one goes down. I can't get it to work properly. Router (GL.inet) is connected to server one. from another computer, i ssh into server one and reboot server one. EXPECTATION: Router(GL.inet) has to switch automatically to server 2. REALITY: Router(Gl.inet) keeps trying to connect to server one. I try to reboot the Router(Gl.inet), it keeps trying to reconnect to server one. After like 1h, it will connecto to server 2. I wanted the switch to be done immediately, or maybe within 5 minutes, not a whole hour.

Here is the configuration file for both servers:

```
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/pivpnservertwo.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/pivpnservertwo.key
remote-cert-tls client
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key 0                                  
dh  dh2048.pem
;tls-verify "./verify-cn /etc/openvpn/allowedClients" 
;crl-verify ""
reneg-sec 3600 
cipher AES-256-CBC                                                      
user nobody                                                             
group nogroup
persist-tun 
persist-key 
persist-local-ip
persist-remote-ip
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" 
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/clientConfigDirectory 
dev tun 
topology subnet 
float
proto udp
port 1194
push-peer-info
max-clients 100
keepalive 5 10 
ping-timer-rem 
log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log 
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/ipassignments.txt                                                                                                                                   
verb 4
status    /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log  1                                            
status-version 1
writepid  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-pid.log
explicit-exit-notify 2
up        ./server.up
down      ./server.down
management 127.0.0.1 3066
```

Here is the configuration file for the client:

```
client                                          
ca ca.crt                                                            
cert chachoo.crt
key chachoo.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1 
reneg-sec 0  
cipher AES-256-CBC  
persist-tun  
persist-key   
mute-replay-warnings
dev tun                                             
remote 192.168.50.100 1194 udp4
remote 192.168.50.150 1194 udp4                                        
remote-random                                                           
resolv-retry infinite 
nobind
connect-retry 5  20 
connect-retry-max 3 
verb 4
```

[image: Here is a picture of the router client i am talking about:]
Here is a picture of the log of the router-client: you can see in the log, it says, preserving recently used remote ip address. i want it to switch to the following remote ip address.
[image: Here is a picture of the log of the router-client: you can see in the log, it says, preserving recently used remote ip address. i want it to switch to the following remote ip address.]

Answer (score 0):

Following this [thread](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=27539)

Try to add the following config to your client conf

```
server-poll-timeout 1
```

Comment: I just tried it. It does switch to the other server, but the connection is not stable, it keeps reconnecting and reconnecting.

Comment: Look at the server and the client logs, and/or add them to your question.

Comment: Maybe 1 sec is not enough time, try `server-poll-timeout 10`